# Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, navigator

navigator.pushandremoveuntil is working fine but an exception is thrown:
This statement is executed from a class that extends ChangeNotifier (provider).

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {return EmailAuthVC();}), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### What is the error?

As the error explains, you are trying to use `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` in the dispose method.

What this really means is that the `context` you are using is no longer part of the widget tree (because its state as been disposed) and therefore you cannot use it to call `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`.

But where are you using `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`? In `Navigator.of(context)`. If you check its source code:

```dart
static NavigatorState of(
  BuildContext context, {
  bool rootNavigator = false,
}) {
  // Handles the case where the input context is a navigator element.
  NavigatorState? navigator;
  if (context is StatefulElement && context.state is NavigatorState) {
    navigator = context.state as NavigatorState;
  }
  if (rootNavigator) {
    navigator = context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>() ?? navigator;
  } else {
    navigator = navigator ?? context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>();
  }
  ...
  return navigator!;
}
```

### How to solve this?

You have to use the context to get the `Navigator` *before* the `dispose` method. As explained in the error, you should create a reference to the object (in the `didChangeDependencies` method for example) and use it latter.

Here is a concrete example:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  // The reference to the navigator
  late NavigatorState _navigator;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(..., (route) => ...);
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

Why not use the `initState` method rather than `didChangeDependencies`? Because, as much as the `context` is not longer valid in `dispose`, the `context` is not yet valid in `initState` because the widget has not yet been inserted in the widget tree.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mention in my question
i'm calling this pushandremoveuntill statement from a class that extends change notifier(provider) 
i'm not using didChangeDependencies anywhere in my code

Comment: As I explain, using Navigator.of(context) is what calls didChangeDependencies so you are indeed using didChangeDependencies. From your comment, I suppose you are passing the context to your change notifier class ? In which case this is not good practice, for two reasons: 1) context should never be kept in a longed lived variable, 2) Your state should be decoupled from your UI and context is part of the UI. What you should do is have a dependency in your change notifier which is populated from the UI. If you need help with this please say so

Comment: @Lulupointu What am I supposed to write intead of "..." when calling pushAndRemoveUntil? It is not working with these 3 dots.

Comment: The first "..." should contain the route to navigate to. The second "..." contains a condition which should return 'true' when the popping of the previous routes should stop. For example: _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => const MyHomePage()), ModalRoute.withName('/'));

Comment: @Lulupointu This is the perfect answer. It clearly describes the issue and the way to resolve it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just a few hours ago I also faced the same problem where I was getting the error exactly the same as you mentioned in your problem.
When I tried to know what exactly is going wrong even on calling a simple navigator, I came to know that I was calling the context of a widget which is already dispose.
Exactly what happened was, I was building a quiz app where the user was to be redirected to the result screen when time is over. So I was calling the navigator as

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: quiz.quizDuration)).then((value) {
    // go to result screen when time is over
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ResultScreen()));
});
```

But the user would also be redirected to the result screen if he answers all questions before time. So this widget would be already disposed and our delayed function will complete after the time and try to use the context of a disposed widget.. So that's the error.

I solved it by checking if the state persists. If widget is still there dispose it, if it is already disposed do nothing.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: quiz.quizDuration)).then((value) {
  // check if is mounted
  if (mounted) {
    // if it is mounted then go to result screen, time is off bro..
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ResultScreen()));
  }
});
```

This is how I solved my problem.. So I guess you can also solve your problem by putting your navigator code inside

```
if(mounted) 
{
// navigator.... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem caused by the fact that I forgot to call timer.cancel() within a Timer.periodic() function.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32700405)